# Jersey Injection Manager Factory error in Karaf OSGi environment on restarting Karaf

Tags: java, osgi, jersey-2.0, karaf

I get the below error related to Injection Manager Factory not found only when i restart my Karaf. Subsequently my REST endpoints do not work .
I can typically get over this issue if i clean out my karaf data directory but i don't want to do this.
My application works normally when i start it the first time without any Jersey related errors , but only on restart this issue shows up.

Any idea what may be causing this problem.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lambda$lookupInjectionManagerFactory$0(Injections.java:98) ~[251:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.27.0]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[?:?]
    a.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lambda$lookupInjectionManagerFactory$0(Injections.java:98) ~[251:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.27.0]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[?:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lookupInjectionManagerFactory(Injections.java:98) ~[251:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.27.0]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:93) ~[251:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.27.0]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282) ~[252:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.27.0]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335) ~[249:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.27.0]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178) ~[249:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.27.0]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370) ~[249:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.27.0]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[53:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0]t org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lookupInjectionManagerFactory(Injections.java:98) ~[251:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.27.0]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:93) ~[251:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.27.0]at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282) ~[252:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.27.0]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335) ~[249:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.27.0]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178) ~[249:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.27.0]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370) ~[249:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.27.0]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[53:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:637) ~[76:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:421) ~[76:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:760) ~[76:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:348) ~[76:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.startContext(HttpServiceContext.java:414) ~[98:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:7.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785) ~[75:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261) ~[76:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doStart(HttpServiceContext.java:267) ~[98:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:7.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[78:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.4.6.v20170531]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.start(JettyServerImpl.java:329) ~[98:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:7.0.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.end(HttpServiceStarted.java:1222) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.end(HttpServiceProxy.java:456) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.end(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:404) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:658) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:228) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:173) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:129) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:870) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:318) ~[?:?]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver.deploy(WebObserver.java:217) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver$1.doStart(WebObserver.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.SimpleExtension.start(SimpleExtension.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.AbstractExtender.lambda$createExtension$0(AbstractExtender.java:277) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:?]
```

Comment: Interestingly i found the following bug which explains my situation aptly.
However that does not explain why i get it only on restarting Karaf and not the first time around.
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish-hk2/issues/359

Comment: Any help , i feel this issue is specific to OSGI environment and how bundles are loaded on restart. If i delete the data folder of Karaf and proceed , everything works just fine . I just have to manually install my features one by one and add the maven repo. Obviously i don't want to be doing that again and again.

Comment: Any solutions you found? @K-ous

Comment: In my case the problem was solved by prioritizing the Jersey and HK2 bundles start order.
Added a Start level to the jersey & hk2 bundles in the features.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was solved by prioritizing the Jersey and HK2 bundles start order. Added a Start level to the jersey & hk2 bundles in the features.xml file.